# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined within setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

Why do I get **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"** when resolving a promise that is within setTimeout()? Like in my example below, calling updateOrder2() where the Promise is wrapped in setTimeout() returns error.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" @change="validateInput(product)"/>
```

in Vue.js

```
validateInput(product) {
   this.updateOrder1(product).then(response => {
     console.log(response); // done!
   });

   this.updateOrder2(product).then(response => {
     console.log(response); // error
   });
},

updateOrder2(product) {
   setTimeout(function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve('done!');
    }, 500);
   });

updateOrder1(product) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve('done!');
   }, 500);
});
```

Comment: `updateOrder1(product) {` should not have 500, I guess that's a typo

Comment: Move setTimeout in promise and resolve it in setTimeout return promise in updateOrder2. when you return setTimeout it return id of setTimeout function which is a number and doesn't have then function in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nothing return anything from *updateOrder2* function, therefore you get a *undefined* when you invoque it. To fix this problem you need to return the promise directly and put the setTimeout inside the promise body like this:

```
updateOrder2(product) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve('done!');
    }, 500);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering this code:

```
function asyncCall() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     resolve('done!');
  }
}

function call(){
  setTimeout(asyncCall, 500)
}
```

Calling `call()` will not execute the asyncCall. it only schedule the execution of `asyncCall` and returns before the `asyncCall` is executed.

`setTimeout()` by itself does not return the results of scheduled code, it only returns the timeoutID.

If you are looking to execute some code after the delayed function has been executed, the best bet is to pass a callback to it.

```
function asyncCall(callback) {
   // execute some delayed code
   callback()
   // Or calling an async function
   asyncFunction().then(() => {
      callback()
   })
}

function call(callback){
  setTimeout(asyncCall, 500, callback)
}

call(function(){
  // This code will be executed after delayed code
})
```